# Call WebAPI method from MVC method passing Mail Message

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a method in my MVC Controller which I am trying to call an API from in order to send an email (The Mail Message is generated in the MVC Method)

Create Mail message is as follows and this works fine.

```
    public static MailMessage CreateMailMessage(string from,
        string to,
        string cc,
        string bcc,
        string subject,
        string body,
        List<Attachment> attachments,
        string differentServer,
        bool eatError)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        mm.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mm.Subject = subject;
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //send to multiple addresses separated by semi-colon or comma      
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(to))
        {
            var toAddresses = to.Split(new char[] { ';', ',' });
            foreach (string toAddress in toAddresses)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(toAddress))
                    mm.To.Add(toAddress);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc))
        {
            mm.CC.Add(cc);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc))
        {
            mm.Bcc.Add(bcc);
        }

        if (attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (Attachment attachment in attachments)
            {
                mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
        }
        return mm;
    }
```

However in order to send the email I need to write and call a WebAPI method - sending the email is fine - just not sure how to post the mail message and some other properties to a WebAPI Method?

So My WebAPI method at the minute is like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to email the Report
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Document/EmailReport/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage EmailFarmFeatures([FromBody]MailMessage email)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

I am attempting to call this WebAPI from MVC Method as below:

```
private void EmailReport(string reportName, byte[] bytes)
{
  ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
  var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
  var attach = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), ct);
  attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = reportName;
  attachments.Add(attach);

  string strFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"];
  string strTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToEmail"];

  string subject = string.Format("Customer Report - {0}", customerId);
  string body = string.Format("Report for Customer {0} attached.", customerId);
  string mailServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"];

  MailMessage message = EmailHelper.CreateMailMessage(strFrom, strTo, "", "", subject, body, attachments, mailServer, false);

  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
    var postRequest = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost/myWS/api/Document/EmailReport/", postRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
      throw new Exception("Error occured emailing report");
    }
  }
}
```

I am currently getting an error on this line:

```
var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

[InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.]
   System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout() +57
   GetReadTimeout(Object ) +81
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target) +114

[JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.]
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target) +274
```

I believe it is something to do with attemptiong to seriliaze the memory stream attachment though I am not sure what the fix is to make sure this attachment gets included on the POST Request to the API Method

Comment: as you suggested yourself, Create a Serializable custom Object  Representing MailMessage (which includes mail message fields ) and sent it via post request

Comment: @esiprogrammer - hi i made some updates to the question - I am getting an issue attempting to serialise this

Comment: Is the Web API method in the same site as the MVC? Or are they hosted in separate websites?

Comment: @mason - hosted in seperate websites in IIS (cant chamge that architecture) however I am writing the code for both

Answer (score 0):

MailMessage isn't Serializable Just create a Separate regular object which represents a mail message.

Have a look at this Thread I guess it's pretty much what you need:

(https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/help-sending-email-mailmessage-deserialize-problem/354/5)[https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/help-sending-email-mailmessage-deserialize-problem/354/5]